# server side socket gets into an infinite loop

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote a server and a client side socket code, if client enters `exit` server side gives a message "Client disconnected from 127.0.0.1: portnumber" and client connection is cut without any problem for both sides and server keeps running as expected. However, when I do `ctrl+c` on the client side, server side gets into an infinite loop. How can I prevent or catch and ignore this and give the same message when client writes "exit". Infinite loop returns `"Client clicked "`

Server side:

```
...
while(1){
    accept(...)
    ...
    if((pid = fork() == 0){
        //close(sock); uncommented this because when I write "exit" it exits as expected but server side throws a "accept:bad file descriptor"
        while(1){
            recv(sock2, buffer, 1024, 0);
            if(strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0){
                printf("Client disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr), ntohs(peer.sin_port) );
                break;
            else{
                printf("Client clicked %s\n",  buffer);
                send(sock2, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }
        }
    }
}
close(sock);
return 0;
```

Client side:

```
...
while(1){
...
if(strcmp(move, "exit") == 0){
        close(sock);
        printf("Disconnected from the server\n");
        exit(0);
    }
...

}
close(sock);
return 0;
```

Comment: Not useful without code.

Comment: @BaseZen very basic server and client socket code, I have a while loop on both server and client sides.

Comment: Very basic sure but also a basic error such as repeatedly reading from a closed socket in a while loop that doesn’t react properly. So, code :-)

Comment: @BaseZen updated :)

Comment: @BaseZen You called it. Well done.

Comment: Also, the usual misuse of library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array on char arrays that are not guaranteed NUL-terminated and failure to correctly handle the octet-stream nature of TCP.

Comment: always check the returned value from `recv()` and `send()`.   When the returned value from `recv()` is 0, the client hungup/disconnected.  Should also check for <0 to catch any I/O errors

Comment: Thank you both and I will check for the return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        recv(sock2, buffer, 1024, 0);
```

You simply ignore the return code of `recv` which returns the number of bytes read. If the client disconnects `recv` will return 0. If an error occurs `recv` will return -1. In both cases the content of `buffer` will be unchanged. Specifically it will not contain `exit` which means your code assumes a click. Thus, don't assume that `buffer` will contain just the read data but make sure that data were actually read by checking the return code of `recv`.

What you should do if `recv` returns error (-1) or eof (0) is to close the socket and exit from the loop which reads from the client, i.e. similar to what you do on `exit`.

Comment: `if(recv(sock2, buffer, 1024, 0) == 0){
         printf("Client disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr), ntohs(peer.sin_port) );
                break;
}`

Solved the problem. Thank you!